# Deprecated Facebook Insights counters

Tags: facebook, counter, facebook-insights

From december 2011, more Facebook Insights counters are deprecated like the following counters :

```
page_active_users
pages_active_users_gender
page_fans_country
page_fans_gender_age
page_fans_adds_source
page_adds_comments
page_like_adds
page_stream_views
page_stream_view_unique
page_wall_posts
page_photos_view
page_photos_view_unique
page_video_plays
page_video_plays_unique
page_audio_plays
page_audio_plays_unique
page_discussions
page_discussions_unique
page_views_login
page_views_logout
page_views_internal_referrals
```

What replaces them ?  How to find these informations now?
What is the alternative ?

Best regards

Christian

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives:

- page_fans_adds_source = page_fans_by_like_source
- page_stream_views = page_posts_impressions
- page_stream_view_unique = page_posts_impressions_unique
- page_views_login = page_views_unique
- page_views_logout = page_views - page_views_unique

Not deprecated:

- page_fans_country
- page_fans_gender_age

No alternatives:

- page_active_users
- page_active_users_gender
- page_comment_adds
- page_like_adds
- page_wall_posts
- page_photos_view
- page_photos_view_unique
- page_video_plays
- page_video_plays_unique
- page_audio_plays
- page_audio_plays_unique
- page_discussions
- page_discussions_unique
- page_views_internal_referrals

Answer (score 0):

It might be an old Thread but just in case check [Metric Substitution](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2144673/Facebook-Deprecating-50-Page-Insights-Metrics-Are-You-Ready)

it has some replacement for deprecated metrics

Ex. Video_plays can be obtained from page_consumptions_by_consumption_type